# Contact Form 7 and cookie value

Tags: wordpress, cookies

Good morning, I'm using Contact Form 7 with email submission after form submission.
Now i need to send by email a value that is stored into a cookie (it is a referral code). How can i do it?

Answer (score 5):

Without any plugin, it is very simple to achieve the same just adding a new custom [Special Mail Tag](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/):

**STEP-1:** Add below code in your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'wpcf7_my_cookie_mailtag', 10, 3 );
function wpcf7_my_cookie_mailtag( $output, $name, $html ) {
    if ( '_my_cookie_special_tag' != $name ) { // rename the tag name as your wish;
        return $output;
    }

    if ( ! $contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current() ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $val = isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']) ? $_COOKIE['my_cookie'] : '';

    return $html ? esc_html($val) : $val;
}
```

**STEP-2:** Use this shortcode `[_my_cookie_special_tag]` in your [Mail Setup](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/).

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to achieve this.

1. Install [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) plugin.
2. Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

   ```
   function dynamictext_cf7_cookie($atts){
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
           'key' => -1,
       ), $atts));

       if($key == -1) return '';
       $val = '';

       if( isset( $_COOKIE[$key] ) ){
           $val = $_COOKIE[$key];
       }

       return $val;
   }
   add_shortcode('DT_CF7_COOKIE', 'dynamictext_cf7_cookie');
   ```
3. Add this to your Contact Form 7 form's 'Form' tab - `[dynamichidden referral-code-field "DT_CF7_COOKIE key='REFERRAL_CODE'"]` where 'REFERRAL_CODE' is your PHP cookie name.
4. Add this to the 'Mail' tab of your Contact Form 7 form - `[referral-code-field]`.

That's it and you can read more here - https://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2014/04/contact-form-7-place-post-server-cookie-session-variables-fields/.

Comment: Great bit of code, thanks. To clarify: if you want to collect the status of a different cookie then you use the same PHP code and just change the cookie ID (REFERRAL_CODE) in the one place, the form tab of your contact form.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation, as per docs, contact form7 wont use cookies.

With the default configuration, this plugin, in itself, does not:

1. track users by stealth;
2. write any user personal data to the database;
3. send any data to external servers;
4. use cookies.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to send another email after a successful contact form 7 submission. You may do this through the available wpcf7 hook in the backend. `wpcf7_mail_sent`

Note: You have to get the cookie data you want and include it on the form dynamically as a hidden field using javascript so that its included in the form submitted which you can retrieve at the backend.

```
//you can place this in your functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
  //do what you want here like get the extra  
});
```

This is how I would do it in the backend end assuming that I already have the data from a cookie added as a hidden field using javascript/jquery e.g. injected `<input type="hidden" name="referral_code" />` inside form tag.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {

    $wpcf7         = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $submission    = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data   = empty($submission) ? null : $submission>get_posted_data();

    //assuming you are tracking a form with an id 1234
    if($wpcf7->id() === 1234){

      //not sure if this still works, if not you can simply use $_GET['referral_code']
      if(isset($posted_data['referral_code'])){
         $referralCode = $posted_data['referral_code'];
         //...now from this point you can send an email or pass this info to another platform for tracking purposes.
      }

    }

});
```